# JS / d3js, calling a CSV; some numbers give NaN error, some don't ... A fix?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm making a little graph using d3.js library.

I'm calling on numbers in a .csv, using d3.csv(). Five columns work fine.

But two columns are allegedly full of "NaN," though they *are* numbers, according to console.log(typeof d.Rate_10)

```
d3.csv("minerals.csv", function(data) 
{
    data.forEach(function(d) 
    {
        d.Value_Total_10 = d.Value_Total_10 // works
        d.Value_Total_11 = d.Value_Total_11 //works

        d.Commodity = d.Commodity   //works

        d.Volume_Total_10 = d.Volume_Total_10 // works
        d.Volume_total_11 = d.Volume_Total_11 // works

        d.Rate_10 = +d.Rate_10 // script is not recognizing these values as numbers.

        console.log(typeof d.Rate_10) //prints "number"
        console.log(d.Rate_10) // prints "NaN"

        d.Rate_11 = +d.Rate_11 // script is not recognizing these values as numbers.

        console.log(typeof d.Rate_11) //prints "number"
        console.log(d.Rate_11); //prints "NaN"

        ...
```

My .csv is an Excel saved as .csv. My troublesome "rate" columns were originally calculated columns, but I retyped them by hand as an attempted fix.  Didn't work.

I understand this has something to do with float or int or IEEE or something, but I don't exactly understand that and all my values are plain 'ol numbers to one or two decimal places.

My .csv is here: http://greencracker.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/minerals.csv

What gives? I don't understand the difference between my working columns and my NaN columns.

Comment: have you tried calling `parseFloat(d.Rate_10)` instead of `+d.Rate_10`? I have a hunch that that might solve the issue.

Comment: The type of NaN is number. This might come as a surprise, but it isn't unexpected behavior.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem from directly parsing your CSV file. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZrCB/

Comment: @Asad, no wonder you can't reproduce it ... now it's not giving me the error either!!  Runs like a dream.  I wonder why it didn't before ... it's just a plain old .csv sitting on my machine, I'm using TextWrangler and Safari 6.0.2.

Comment: @greencracker Good to know. If you can identify the steps you took to solve the problem, you should post them as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Maus I am going to keep that little call handy.  Bet I'll use it.

Comment: This happened again with some different data.  For real, I closed every program, restarted the computer for good measure ... and then the code worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Was just experiencing the same problem.

I csv file I was importing d3.csv and some numbers were returning NaN. Turns out my problem was the csv file.

I created it using excel and in one of the columns I was importing I had about 3 cells at around row 3,000 that were formatted as "number". Which means excel had placed a comma in the number as a thousands separator. Reformatted column as general with no commas or extra formatting. Voila